# How to handle SQLPackage.exe full transaction log error for deploying dacpac?

Tags: sql-server, logging, dacpac, sqlpackage

I recently automatize deployment of SSIS projects and SQL Server database with powershell scripts.
I use SQLPackage.exe (dacpac framework) to deploy .dacpac in order to automatize update database structure. **My issue**: Dacpac try to **rebuild** huge tables and fail with following error message as "transaction log full".

I found a **solution** by copying all data in temporal database, truncating actual database, update with dacpac and copying data back. **Really important points to notice**:

- I must save data somewhere.
- During copy of data I explicitly copy data in small batches of 50000 lines and clean database log file to prevent error.

**My question: is there an option in SQLPackages /deploy which allow to handle this process more easily? Or another way I did not think of?**

[image: log error in windows command line]

Comment: Looks like you are either adding or removing columns or changing data types.  sqlpackage.exe needs to keep a copy of the data so it can easily roll back in case of an error. So the larger the table, the more space is needed.  You can expand the database/log, or do the DDL operations manually so sqlpackage.exe doesn't have to do it.